# Add custom text message after break line

Tags: python, yagmail

The below code snippet sends email with status.
If I want to add another line break with text as Sent from Scheduler.
What could be the possible way ?

```
def send_email(status,message):
    date = str(datetime.now().date())[-5:].replace('-', '/')
    yag.send(to=TO_EMAIL,subject="{} Rebuild Code: {}".format(date, status),contents=message)
    logging.info("Mail Sent!")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this updated code.

**Update**:

```
def send_email(status,message):
    date = str(datetime.now().date())[-5:].replace('-', '/')
    message = "{}\n{}".format(message, 'Sent from Scheduler'
    yag.send(to=TO_EMAIL,subject="{} Rebuild Code: {}".format(date, status),contents=message))
    logging.info("Mail Sent!")
```

Here, instead of just returning the message, it can be updated as `"{}\n{}".format(message, 'Sent from Scheduler')`
`\n` is the single line break. If you want multiple line breaks you can use `\n\n`.

Comment: contents=message cannot be removed as it posts the Message inside the email content. I want to add one more line & do not want to edit or remove the existing.

Comment: I've updated the code. Just try to print `message` before `yag.send` to see what it prints.

Comment: Looking at the code seems it will mostly print: Sent from Scheduler. The purpose was to add this line not to replace the existing message lines.